# .htaccess - redirection (remove first "-" in the link)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I work now on set of different redirection rules on the big sets of links. So for example if i want add a "-" after "temp" as in example:

```
tempfile-abc1.php > temp-file-abc1.php
tempfile-def2.php > temp-file-def2.php
tempfile-ghi3.php > temp-file-ghi3.php
```

i use following code:

```
 RewriteRule ^(temp)(file-.+\.php)$ /$1-$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

But what I would like to do now is to reverse it so to remove first "-" hyphen from the link. I require 1 rule/cond for the set of links as for example:

```
temp-file-abc1.php > tempfile-abc1.php
temp-file-def2.php > tempfile-def2.php
temp-file-ghi3.php > tempfile-ghi3.php
```

I will appreciate any suggestion / solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works form me:

```
 RewriteRule ^(temp-file)(-.+\.php)$ /tempfile$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also contain an explanation.

Comment: (temp-file) 1 part is being replaced with stactic tempfile, (-.+\.php) is everything after  "-" as $2

Answer (score 2):

Try below rule I am assuming tempfile is static,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(temp)-(file)-([\w-]+)\.php$ tempfile-$3.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: you opend my eyes here